# Which OCR Engine is better: Tesseract or OCRopus?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, feature-extraction

I have tried Tesseract with iPhone and assessed its accuracy to be 70% without image preprocessing. I also noticed that it might be poor in extracting digits. I have heard about OCRopus OCR engine: which is better, Tesseract or OCRopus, in terms of digit extraction and if my image preprocessing is low?
Has anyone run tests using both engines comparing the results using the usual metrics?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. OCR engines can be compared to each other for accuracy -- it's a very objective comparison. Not much "opion-based".

Comment: Are there any other open-source tools, like OCRopus and Tesseract with better performance accuracy?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Initially OCRopus was actually using Tesseract as recognition engine inside, but later they changed it to their own brand-new engine. It is still fresh and not mature. We have been making accuracy comparison about year ago, and OCRopus was definitely losing to Tesseract, I am not even talking about commercial enignes. Since then I stopped following OCRopus progress, but what I definetely know that activity on OCRopus support forum is close to zero now. That means, no one is using it. Mostly people are using commercial engines, but if price is an issue for them and they can tolerate lower accuracy, then they use Tesseract. It is definetely best one among Open Source.

Comment: Hi Tomato, if we want to use commercial engines, what would you recommend?

Comment: @KimStacks, I think this answer is outdated. Can you please update based on your latest knowledge. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the activity of projects in "changes" link

https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/source/list?repo=ocropy

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/list

tesseract is much busier

Comment: Can you update this answer please @IvanM